# How to overlap the child element of a grid item to the next column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

So, i want to build a calendar, which displays the current month. So I build the calender with an css grid. Now i want to add events, which could durate longer than a day(a is a grid item). The problem I face now, is that the div element, which should display my event, is the child element of the grid item, so I can't just add `grid-column: span 2;` to adjust the length of the event over multiple days.
How can a child of the grid-item (which is the day of the month) can overlap to the next calendar day?

Edit:
To turn up the width to 200% would be a solution,but then the event of the next day wouldn't align with the current event. At the latest, at window resize, those two lines wouldn't line up anymore.
[image]

I made a quick mock of my project to show the problem more visually:
https://codepen.io/eliasroebl/pen/yLMXOwy

```
<div class="Calendar calendar">
  <div class="calendar__header">
    <div>Monday</div>
    <div>Tuesday</div>
    <div>Wednesday</div>
    <div>Thursday</div>
    <div>Friday</div>
    <div>Saturday</div>
    <div>Sunday</div>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__week">
    <div class="calendar__day day">1</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">2</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">3</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">4</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">5</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">6</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__week">
    <div class="calendar__day day">8</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">9
      <div class="event">
        Event 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">10</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">11</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">12</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">13</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">14</div>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__week">
    <div class="calendar__day day">15</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">16</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">17</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">18</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">19</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">20</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">21</div>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__week">
    <div class="calendar__day day">22</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">23</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">24</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">25</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">26</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">27</div>
    <div class="calendar__day day">28</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.calendar__week,
.calendar__header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}
.calendar__week {
  grid-auto-rows: 6vw;
  text-align: right;
}

.different_month_days{
  background-color: #c1d5e0;
}


.event{
  grid-column: col 2 / span 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 5vw;
  text-align: left;
}



.calendar__header {
  grid-auto-rows: 3vw;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #8f9bff;

}

.calendar__day {
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

.calendar {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.calendar__header > div {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.calendar__day {
  border-right: 1px solid  #e1e1e1;
  border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;

}

.calendar__day:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

Thanks already for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here you go...**

*Inspired by [this](https://codepen.io/oliviale/pen/QYqybo) codepen.*

I changed the code a little bit and made it more responsive because the source code on codepen wasn't responsive at all. Colorful boxes and all the text (days of the week, numbers and event text) are now responsive.

I solved your main problem with events not aligning when resizing the window. The events now align *perfectly* regardless of the window size.

For example, the first event with `class='event--1'` starts at the third box and is spread across the next two boxes which is done with `grid-column: 3 / span 2;`. The second event with `class='event--2'` starts at the fourth box and is spread across the next three boxes which is done with `grid-column: 4 / span 3;`.

But you also have to put these boxes which have assigned events kind of "back into place". For the fifteenth box this is done with the following CSS:

```
div.date:nth-child(15) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

Try to delete this from the CSS and you will get the point.

Also, I used a little bit of Bootstrap 5 to be able to vertically align days of the week.

```css
.days {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  height: 8vh;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.main-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 35vh);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(calc(100vw/7), 1fr));
}

.date {
  background: var(--color);
  padding: 4%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

.event {
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent;
  height: 10%;
  padding-top: 2.3vw;
}

.event--1 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.event--2 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  padding-top: 6vw;
}

.event__name {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10vw;
  height: 2.5vh;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 0.9vw;
}

div.date:nth-child(15) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}

div.date:nth-child(16) {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}

div.date:nth-child(17) {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: 3;
}

div.date:nth-child(18) {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='d-flex align-items-center days'>
    <div class='col text-center'>Monday</div>
    <div class='col text-center'>Tuesday</div>
    <div class='col text-center'>Wednesday</div>
    <div class='col text-center'>Thursday</div>
    <div class='col text-center'>Friday</div>
    <div class='col text-center'>Saturday</div>
    <div class='col text-center'>Sunday</div>
  </div>

  <div class='main-content'>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db7f7a'>1</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db847a'>2</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db8d7a'>3</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db8d7a'>4</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db917a'>5</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db967a'>6</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db9a7a'>7</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db9a7a'>8</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#db9f7a'>9</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dba37a'>10</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dba87a'>11</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbac7a'>12</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbb07a'>13</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbb57a'>14</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbbe7a'>15</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbc27a'>16</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbc77a'>17</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbd07a'>18</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbd47a'>19</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#dbd97a'>20</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#d9db7a'>21</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#d0db7a'>22</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#cbdb7a'>23</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#c7db7a'>24</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#c2db7a'>25</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#bedb7a'>26</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#b9db7a'>27</div>
    <div class='date' style='--color:#b5db7a'>28</div>

    <div class='event event--1'>
      <div class='event__name d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>Valentines party with Ames ❤️</div>
    </div>
    <div class='event event--2'>
      <div class='event__name d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>Die Hard binge weekend </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.
I appreciate how fast you found a solution. The only thing, which still bugging me, is that, if I have an event on the next day the two events doesn't line up.

I updated the codepen to visualize what I mean.
Is there anything I can do to fix that issue?

Comment: These two events do align if I look at your edited codepen in the full-page mode. Can you explain a little bit more, what do you mean? I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuarcy. Yes, in fullscreen it's perfect, but as soon someone resizes the window, the events doesn't align anymore.
I stated that issue a little closer in an update of the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldve used a table make this ,anyways here is what you should do
change the event css like this

```
.event{
  grid-column: col 2 / span 4;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 5vw;
  text-align: left;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

and then lets say you want a particular event to go on for 2 days then use this,

```
<div class="event" style="width:200%;">
        Event 1
      </div>
```

width will be 100 * no of days this is how it looks now
[image]
hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.
I appreciate how fast you found a solution. The only thing, which still bugging me, is that, if I have an event on the next day the two events doesn't line up.

I updated the codepen to visualize what I mean.
Is there anything I can do to fix that issue?

Comment: you should upvote and mark the answer correct to help other coders in future,

Comment: I did not fully understand your problem ,but here is a solution to what I understood use `position:relative;` and remove `margintop;`

Comment: I will upvote and mark the answer correct as soon my problem is fully solved.I really thank you for your help so far.
What I meant is, your solution works fine when the window is on full size. But as soon as I resize the window, the div element of the last day gets horizontally shorter than the div element of the current day.
I updated my question to explain this usecase a little bit closer.

And what did you want to achieve with switching margin top and position: relative?

Again thanks for your help so far. I appreciate it.